# parsing across multiple lines with ansible

Tags: ansible

So I have an inventory output from a device that looks like this:

```
Name: "Chassis", DESCR: "ASA 5555-X with SW, 8 GE Data, 1 GE Mgmt"
PID: ASA5555           , VID: V05     , SN: FTXxxxxxD1

Name: "power supply 0", DESCR: "ASA 5545-X/5555-X AC Power Supply"
PID: ASA-PWR-AC        , VID: N/A     , SN: 6BxxNN

Name: "power supply 1", DESCR: "ASA 5545-X/5555-X AC Power Supply"
PID: ASA-PWR-AC        , VID: N/A     , SN: 6AxxxP

Name: "Storage Device 1", DESCR: "Model Number: Micron_M600_MTFDDAK128MBF"
PID: N/A               , VID: N/A     , SN: MSxxxxxKZ

Name: "Storage Device 2", DESCR: "Model Number: Micron_M600_MTFDDAK128MBF"
PID: N/A               , VID: N/A     , SN: MSAxxxxxYS
```

This is the task that use to split the output, that the two corresponding lines for an item become a item in a list:

```
 - name: split lines
      set_fact:
        item_list: "{{ inventory.stdout.split('\n\n') }}"
```

Debug show this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "Name: \"Chassis\", DESCR: \"ASA 5555-X with SW, 8 GE Data, 1 GE Mgmt\"\nPID: ASA5555           , VID: V05     , SN: FTX21xxxxx3",
        "Name: \"power supply 0\", DESCR: \"ASA 5545-X/5555-X AC Power Supply\"\nPID: ASA-PWR-AC        , VID: N/A     , SN: 6xxxxxN",
        "Name: \"power supply 1\", DESCR: \"ASA 5545-X/5555-X AC Power Supply\"\nPID: ASA-PWR-AC        , VID: N/A     , SN: 6AxxxxP",
        "Name: \"Storage Device 1\", DESCR: \"Model Number: Micron_M600_MTFDDAK128MBF\"\nPID: N/A               , VID: N/A     , SN: MSAxxxxxxxZ",
        "Name: \"Storage Device 2\", DESCR: \"Model Number: Micron_M600_MTFDDAK128MBF\"\nPID: N/A               , VID: N/A     , SN: MSA2xxxxxxS"
    ]
}
```

But I cannot get this into a proper dictionary with key value pairs for my next task.
Isn't there an easier method or parsing the text directly into a dict?

Comment: You are not showing the task from which you get that output from (and "inventory output" is a quite confusing term in this context). Please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: It is the output of a single command that I store in the inventory variable. I just replaced the part to execute that command on the remote device with a simple cat on a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the filter *from_yaml* to convert the items to dictionaries. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dev: "{{ dev|d([]) + [_dict|from_yaml] }}"
      loop: "{{ inventory.stdout.split('\n\n') }}"
      vars:
        _dict: "{ {{ item.split('\n')|join(',') }} }"
```

gives

```yaml
  dev:
  - DESCR: ASA 5555-X with SW, 8 GE Data, 1 GE Mgmt
    Name: Chassis
    PID: ASA5555
    SN: FTXxxxxxD1
    VID: V05
  - DESCR: ASA 5545-X/5555-X AC Power Supply
    Name: power supply 0
    PID: ASA-PWR-AC
    SN: 6BxxNN
    VID: N/A
  - DESCR: ASA 5545-X/5555-X AC Power Supply
    Name: power supply 1
    PID: ASA-PWR-AC
    SN: 6AxxxP
    VID: N/A
  - DESCR: 'Model Number: Micron_M600_MTFDDAK128MBF'
    Name: Storage Device 1
    PID: N/A
    SN: MSxxxxxKZ
    VID: N/A
  - DESCR: 'Model Number: Micron_M600_MTFDDAK128MBF'
    Name: Storage Device 2
    PID: N/A
    SN: MSAxxxxxYS
    VID: N/A
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Slim elegant code.